# $collection->setPage(0,5) returning all products in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I want to get products in 5 5 groups. I am using

> $collection->setPage() method

but it always returns all products.

```
$Category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(12); 
$collection = $Category->getProductCollection();
$tot = $collection->setPage(0,5);
echo count($tot);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->limit(20);
```

It always returns a total number of products from the list.

I also used:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(12)->getCollection();
$collection->setPageSize(10);
```

How can I group the first five products in one array after 6th to 10th products in another array?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my version of the solution can help you

```
$i = 1;
do{
    $Category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->setPageSize($page_length);
    $page1 = $collection->setCurPage(1)->load();
    foreach ($collection as $value) {
     //...
    }
    $collection->clear();
    $i++;
}while ($i <= 2);
```